# Python Regex: having trouble with # of occurrance

Tags: python, regex

Can someone tell me why the following does not match:

```
>>> re.search(r'(\d{2, 10})', '153')
```

and this one matches:

```
>>> re.search(r'\d{3}', '153')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x02110368>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `re` module does not like the space after the `2,`:

```
In [2]: re.search(r'(\d{2, 10})', '153')

In [4]: re.search(r'(\d{2,10})', '153')
Out[4]: <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x15c4648>
```

Once you have the space in there, the expression inside the braces is no longer recognized as the repetition operator. Instead, it becomes a literal match looking for `{2, 10}`:

```
In [11]: re.search(r'(\d{2, 10})', '1{2, 10}').group(0)
Out[11]: '1{2, 10}'
```